# Trying to make Google SignIn helper but 'uiDelegate must either be a |UIViewController|

Tags: swift, google-signin

I'm trying to make Google social helper is NSObject outside of ViewController. I'm present SignIn using UIApplication extension in root ViewController, but I still have an error.

> 'uiDelegate must either be a |UIViewController| or implement the |signIn:presentViewController:| and |signIn:dismissViewController:| methods from |GIDSignInUIDelegate|.'

This my social helper object

```
import GoogleSignIn

class GidHelper: NSObject, GIDSignInUIDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {

private let succesAuth: (String, String, String, String) -> ()
private let failedAuth: (Error) -> ()

init(succesAuth: @escaping (String, String, String, String) -> (), failedAuth: @escaping (Error) -> ()) {
    self.succesAuth = succesAuth
    self.failedAuth = failedAuth
    super.init()
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
}

func openGidAuthorization() {
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
}

func gidLogout() {
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()
}

// Present a view that prompts the user to sign in with Google
private func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!,
                    presentViewController viewController: UIViewController!) {
    UIApplication.topViewController()?.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

private func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!,
                    dismissViewController viewController: UIViewController!) {
    UIApplication.topViewController()?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
    if let error = error {
        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        self.failedAuth(error)
    } else {
        let userId = user.userID
        let accessToken = user.authentication.accessToken 
        let userAvatarUrl = user.profile.imageURL(withDimension: 100)?.absoluteString
        let email = user.profile.email
        self.succesAuth(accessToken!, userId!, email!, userAvatarUrl!)
    }
}
}
```

My UIApplication extension:

```
  import Foundation
  import UIKit

  extension UIApplication {
        class func topViewController(controller: UIViewController? = 
  UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let navigationController = controller as? UINavigationController {
            return topViewController(controller: navigationController.visibleViewController)
        }
        if let tabController = controller as? UITabBarController {
            if let selected = tabController.selectedViewController {
                return topViewController(controller: selected)
            }
        }
        if let presented = controller?.presentedViewController {
            return topViewController(controller: presented)
        }
        return controller
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your implementation of `GidHelper` class look very weird starting from the init and finishing with this extension:(. I recommend you to create a service (let it be your `GoogleLoginService`), make it a singleton and create also a NavigationService instead of this mess with extension. Here is some ideas how to implement this:

```
import GoogleSignIn
final class GoogleLoginService: NSObject {

typealias SignInResponse = (_ user: User?, _ error: Error?) -> ()

static let sharedInstance = GoogleLoginService()
private var presenter: UIViewController?
private var singInCompletion: SignInResponse?

//Call next function in appDelegate: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
@discardableResult func registerInApplication(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "GoogleService-Info", withExtension: "plist"),
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
        let dictionary = try? PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, options: [], format: nil) as? [String : AnyObject]
        if let clientID = dictionary??["CLIENT_ID"] {
            GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = clientID as? String
        }
    }
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    return true
}

// Call this function in AppDelegate: open url
@discardableResult func handleURLIn(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
}

// MARK: - UserManagement

func signIn(_ controller: UIViewController, completion: SignInResponse?) {
    singInCompletion = completion
    presenter = controller
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
}

func signOut() {
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()
}

func isLoggedIn() -> Bool {
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain()
}
}

extension GoogleLoginService: GIDSignInDelegate {

// MARK: - GIDSignInDelegate

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
            if let error = error {
                self.singInCompletion?(nil, error)
                return
            }
            guard let authentication = user.authentication else {
                self.singInCompletion?(nil, error)
                return
            }
            let googleUserObj = User(name: user.profile.name) // <-- You can get your user data 
        }
    }

extension GoogleLoginService: GIDSignInUIDelegate {

    // MARK: - GIDSignInUIDelegate

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, present viewController: UIViewController!) {
        presenter?.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, dismiss viewController: UIViewController!) {
        presenter = nil
        viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Now using `isLoggedIn` method you can save a result in lets say UserDefaults and using NavigationService check if user is logged in or not and go to a proper view controller (as example have a look on the following method of `NavigavionService`:

```
func presentCurrentUserUI() {
    // next line is extension on UserDefaults which keep Bool value - result of logging procedure
    if UserDefaults().isLoggedIn { 
        let homeViewController = UIStoryboard(name: StoryboardName.main, bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()
        self.window?.rootViewController = homeViewController
    } else {
        let loginViewController = UIStoryboard(name: StoryboardName.login, bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()
        self.window?.rootViewController = loginViewController
    }
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Hope it will help you to refactor your code and avoid this error:) Good luck!